# Using anaconda with multiple conda env

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I have to create `conda env` anytime I create a new project. Recently I found out that `anaconda` creates every single package in its environment even if it exists in the base `anaconda` package. So in this situation is it rational using `anaconda`?

Comment: You don't _have_ to create environments at all. You are free to use the base environment however you wish. This is nothing specific to Anaconda; that's just a _distribution_ of python that happens to be very convenient on Windows, especially if you need scientific libraries. The decision to make virtual environments is separate

Comment: @roganjosh I got you ,but the question is if i have to create virtual env for every project does any benefit using anaconda instead of pure python as default python distribution in my system?

Comment: As I already said, Anaconda is a distribution that helps with installing scientific libraries on Windows. The question of having virtual environments for each project is nothing to do with Anaconda itself. The purpose of the question seems confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing great by creating separate environment for each of your projects. The aim of environments is to keep your projects dependencies separate. This means, your project will have only necessary packages.

The problem of using a single environment is that if you update some packages, you are most likely going to destroy something. Example, if you have a project that works only in PACKAGE 1.0, install a package that would update your PACKAGE 1.0 is going to break all your scripts that depends on it. The large the environment, the more likely you would break some dependence. By having separate environments, you are sure that your scripts would always run :)

Another beautiful thing is that of reproducibility. You can save your dependence with there right Python versions.

Update: A simple answer

No, you don’t have too create environment for each project. It is a good practice but not a must. If the project uses the same packages, then reusing environments is a smart move. But the moment there exists differences in used packages, then I would recommend separate environments.

Comment: i know the benefit of separate environment itself , but the question is if i have to create virtual env for every project does any benefit using anaconda instead of pure python as default python distribution in my system?

Comment: No, you don’t have too. It is a good practice. I have some environments that I use again and again doing similar tasks

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I'd agree that using *Conda* is good practice (for the reasons you've listed), but the full Anaconda distribution is probably just bloat for most users. Personally, I think most users should only be using Miniconda.

Comment: Totally true. I use only miniconda. Anaconda comes with lots of stuff I never used.